Cannot find spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client no matter the version
I am trying to import the spring-boot-start-oauth2-client into my pom.xml. I have tried using different versions and no matter which version I use, this error pops up:
Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:3.3.1' not found

Keep in mind the 3.3.1 changes into different versions depending on what version I put. This is the specific part of my pom.xml(let me know if you want the whole file):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   
    <groupId>com.lumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>lumber-integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Parent POM for Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version> <!-- Use the appropriate Spring Boot version -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <!-- Project properties -->
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Dependencies -->

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Micrometer core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version> <!-- Adjust version as per availability -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok for easier Java development -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Dependency management to ensure compatible versions -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- Build plugins -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>


The error is happening at this specific part of the above file:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

I have also tried using the dependencyManagement tool and that gets rid of the error but when I run the code it gives me this error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource 

and
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter

I have tried the solution from this problem here but it did not help because I already had that in my pom.xml: Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE
Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

This question is similar to: Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you set
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

in your project tag?

Upvote, because it might something as stupid (that https://start.spring.io/ would solve ) but such users very rarely accept answers. Keep up with patience and will to help.. ;)

I have already done that I will edit the question to keep my whole pom.xml file there. Thank you for your help but the error still persists.
